# VBox (from Flex) in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, apache-flex, flash, adobe

I had worked in the IDE of Adobe Flex Builder for quite a while.  Is there a simple equivalent to VBox (Flex) in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so.  If you read [this blog post](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/forget_absolute_positioning_in_vs2008.aspx), you'll want to begin honing your CSS skills.  Positioning appears to be a hot topic in the ASP.net world.

Answer (score 0):

When you move to ASP.NET you will be working in a native browser environment. Flex, SilverLight, and other RIAs (Rich Internet Applications) have the advantage of allowing you to completely control the user experience. With native browser development, the user controls a good deal of the experience.

This is why it is so popular users. Darn users... always wanting thing **their way**.

So, to answer your question, there is currently nothing in Visual Studio to give you a similar experience.

And because of that, **you'll want to sharpen your CSS skills**.